# XSLT coding is missing something - xsl:choose

Tags: xslt

I'm new to XSLT and have been coding XML for a short while. I have a need to use the xsl:choose element, but when I try to use the code in an application, for an XML export, I get the following message.
"Export XSLT - XSLT element may not contain XSLT element."

I'm looking to be able to produce Value1 if Value2 is blank, or Value2 if it is not blank.  The coding is pasted below.  Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber=' '">
    <xsl:value-of select="override_segment_charged_dynamic_org_level_onsitedepartment"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="override_segment_dynamic_labor_metric_code_CostNumber"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: xsl:choose can't be a child of xsl:stylesheet; you need to put it in an xsl:template that matches something. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help us give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: Daniel Haley's response was very helpful and I was able to resolve the issue with his post. Not sure how to accept his response as the solution, though.

Comment: Glad my comment helped. I added an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xsl:choose` can't be a child of `xsl:stylesheet`; you need to put it in an xsl:template that matches something.